# Redirecting to another website through link in api

Tags: html, vue.js

I made a loop that generates flip cards by fetching information from the JSON file. When the card is flipped there is a button. How can I make it so that when I press the button it redirects me to the Amazon page of the product but it takes the link from my JSON file? 
I tried doing something like this but it loads it on the page and doesn't redirect.

```
<a data-fancybox="images" v-bind:href="book.detail">
  <button class="fancybox" v-on:click="book.detail">
    Show More
  </button>
</a>
```

JSON file

```
"books": [
    {
      "cover": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51A4OUiN6TL._SX377_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg",
      "title": "The Magic Of Reality",
      "detail": "https://www.amazon.com/Magic-Reality-Know-Whats-Really/dp/1451675046",
      "description": "Richard Dawkins, bestselling author and the world’s most celebrated evolutionary biologist, has spent his career elucidating the many wonders of science. Here, he takes a broader approach and uses his unrivaled explanatory powers to illuminate the ways in which the world really works.",
      "language": "en"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't embed a button in an anchor (a) tag.

```
<a data-fancybox="images" v-bind:href="book.detail">
    Show More
</a>
```

This should work fine!

Comment: If you want the styling of a button, you should apply that styling on the anchor tag instead.

Comment: Thank you it worked, also there was some problem with fancy box thing. It was trying to load on the same page but I deleted it and now works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<button @click="document.location.href=book.detail">
    Show More
  </button>
```